# How to translate this Python script to C#?

Tags: python, c#, translate

I have a script written in Python language, I would like to see how it would look in C#.

```
def combis(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    for x in (1, 3, 4):
        for combi in combis(n-x):
            yield [x] + combi

>>> list(combis(5))
```

Currently I don't understand how to implement this code in C#, what distracts me are those yields and in which type should be my method written.
What I have at the moment is not working and not understandable

```
static int[]  Combs(int n)
        {
            int[] tusc = { };

            if (n < 0)
                yield break;
            if (n == 0)
                yield return tusc;
            int[] X = { 1, 3, 4 };
            for(int i = 0; i < X.Length; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j <= Combs(n-X[i]).Length; j++)
                {
                    yield return X + j;
                }

            }

        }
```

The output of python script, when n equal to 5 is:

```
>>> list(combis(5))
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1], [1, 4], [3, 1, 1], [4, 1]]
```

When n is equal to 4:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3], [3, 1], [4]]
```

Comment: the yield in python works equal to the yield in c#?

Comment: I think principle is the same, but I get confused about type of variables and method

Comment: can you write some outputs with the python method (for n=1,2,3,4 for example) please. It will help to test the c# code implementation

Comment: @Marlonchosky sure, I added expected output from Python script when n is equal to 5, then the output is `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1], [1, 4], [3, 1, 1], [4, 1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HowToTranslateInCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<List<int>> Combis(int n)
        {
            if (n >= 0)
            {
                if (n == 0)
                    yield return new List<int>();
                else
                {
                    foreach (var x in new[] {1, 3, 4})
                    {
                        foreach (var combi in Combis(n - x))
                        {
                            var list = new List<int>() {x};
                            list.AddRange(combi);
                            yield return list;
                        }
                    }        
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = Combis(5);

            foreach (var list in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(" ", list)}]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output is

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 3]
[1 3 1]
[1 4]
[3 1 1]
[4 1]
```

Comment: and when n is 4, the output is [1 1 1 1] [1 3] [3 1] [4]